# How to define own aggregate function in Mysql for GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a `products` table with product names in different languages:

```
product-id | lang-no | name
```

I want to list each product **once**, but using a different language name.

I dont't have all languages for all product names, so I have to fall back onto another language sometimes.

To pick the language with the lowest or highest number I use

```
SELECT * FROM products JOIN
(SELECT product-id, MIN(lang-no) AS minlang FROM products GROUP BY product-id)
AS u ON products.product-id = u.product-id AND products.lang-no=minlang
```

But now I need to define another aggregate function instead of MIN or MAX so I can prefer lang-no 3 for example.

How do i define my own aggregate function in Mysql, eg. some IF logic ?

Comment: If a `Product` can have many languages and you want us to use a *different* language, then what should the chosen language be different from?

Comment: @toonice: When I make a list with Spanish names, its better to use the English or any other name in the list than to leave the product out completely. Right now i don't have a preference for the fallback language. Any is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each product to appear once, then one method is to use variables:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             (@rn := if(@pid = p.product_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@pid := p.product_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from products p cross join
           (select @pid := -1, @rn := 0) params
      order by product_id, field(lang_no, 3, 4, 1, 5, 2) -- or whatever
     ) p
where rn = 1;
```

Another method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*
from products p
where p.lang_no = (select p2.lang_no
                   from products p2
                   where p2.product_id = p.product_id
                   order by field(lang_no, 3, 4, 1, 5, 2)  -- or whatever
                   limit 1
                  );
```

Both these versions use `field()`.  This allows you to list all languages with their priority.

In your case, the correlated subquery is probably faster, assuming you have an index on `product_id`.

The one caveat is that all languages should be listed, because the missing values get a 0.  If that is an issue, use this logic:

```
field(lang_no, 1, 3) desc
```

This will put 3 as the first priority, 1 as the second, and then anything else.

Comment: I like the correlated subquery and language priorities using field(). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` with aggregates to specify which value to return if present and if not min (or max) value:

```
select p.*
from products p
join (
    select product_id,
        case 
            when sum(lang_no = 3) > 0
                then 3
            else min(lang_no)
            end as min_lang_no
    from products
    group by product_id
    ) p2 on p.product_id = p2.product_id
    and p.lang_no = p2.min_lang_no
```

Comment: I like the CASE idea, but is the SUM() in the CASE really correct ? If I only have names for language codes 4 and 5 then the product would be skipped with your query...

Comment: @GeneVincent - Yes it's correct in MySQL context. In other DBMSes, you'll need to use a case inside SUM. Like - `SUM(case when lang_no = 3 then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: `when max(lang_no = 3)` and `when bit_and(lang_no = 3)` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

The following will choose the `name` in the preferred language.  If the name is not available in the preferred language, then it will choose whichever language has the largest value of `lang_no`.

```
SELECT product_id,
       langNum,
       name
FROM ( SELECT products.product_id AS product_id,
              CASE
                  WHEN hasPreferredLang = 0 THEN
                      maxLangNum
                  ELSE
                      preferredLang
              END AS langNum
       FROM ( SELECT product_id AS product_id,
                     MAX( lang_no ) AS maxLangNum
              FROM products
              GROUP BY product_id
            ) AS maxLangNumFinder
       JOIN ( SELECT product_id AS product_id,
                     SUM( CASE
                              WHEN lang_no = preferredLang THEN
                                  1
                              ELSE
                                  0
                          END ) AS hasPreferredLang
              FROM products
              GROUP BY product_id
            ) AS hasPreferredLangFinder ON hasPreferredLang.product_id = maxLangNumFinder.product_id
     ) AS preferredLangNumFinder
JOIN products ON preferredLangNumFinder.langNum = products.lang_no
                 preferredLangNumFinder.product_id = products.product_id;
```

The statement starts by determining what the maximum available value of `lang_no` is for each value of `product_id`.  This is so we can determine a value of `lang_no` to use where the `product_id` does not have an entry for the preferred language.

This subquery is then `INNER JOIN`ed to another that lists each `product_id` along with a value of `0` to indicate if the `product_id` does not have the preferred language associated with it or `1` where it does.

The subquery's results are then used to test if each `product_id` has the preferred language.  If it does then the preferred language is returned.  If it does not then the largest available value of `lang_no` is used.

The resulting list of `product_id` values and their chosen `lang_no` values is then `INNER JOIN`ed to `products` on the shared values of `product_id` and `lang_no`, with the `product_id`, chosen `lang_no` and `name` for the chosen language being `SELECT`ed from the resulting dataset.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM products p1
WHERE p1.lang_no = (
    SELECT p2.lang_no
    FROM products p2
    WHERE p2.product_id = p1.product_id
    ORDER BY p2.lang_no = 3 DESC, p2.lang_no ASC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

The correlated subquery will return `3` if this `lang_no` exists for that product or the least `long_no` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong and violation of db structure & normalization rules.

As many languages have many products so I suggest you create two separate tables for product and language and link them via identity table.

so I recommand:

```
Product:
ProductId ProductName

Language:
LanguageId LanguageName

Product_Lanugage:
ProductId Languageid
```

The query would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products p INNER JOIN
Product_language pl on p.productid=pl.prouctid 
INNER JOIN language l on l.lanugageid=pl.languageid
where l.languagename like %(anylanuage)%
```